# Python error: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python

I have a file: `lib/deep_restore.py` that has:

```
from ..utils.model_loader import load_masking_model, load_reconstruction_model
```

And in `utils/model_loader.py`, I have:

```
import glob
import importlib
import json
import sys
import torch
import os.path as path


def load_masking_model(wandb_id, device, make_4d=False):
    wandb_dir = list(glob.iglob(
        path.join('wandb', '*' + wandb_id), recursive=False))[0]
    model_path = path.join(wandb_dir, 'best-model.pt')

    (head, tail) = path.split(model_path)
    ...
```

From `evaluate.py`, I have:

```
from lib.deep_restore import DeepRestore
```

but I get the error: `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "lib" and "utils" are separate packages in this scenario. Relative imports are relative to a single package.

Comment: So how do I rectify this?

Comment: Put them both in the same package or use absolute imports.

Comment: How do I do an absolute import?

Comment: You tried to move back a directory with `..`. You should place your package in the same directory as the main program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that Python does not see your "utils" and "lib" packages as part of another, larger, package. 
Instead, as far as Python knows, there is one package named "utils" and another named "lib" - and relative imports - which is, prefixing a module name with "." so that Python searches from the current folder inside a package, will only work inside the same package.

Changing this to an absolute import is easy - just remove the "."s:

```
from utils.model_loader import load_masking_model, load_reconstruction_model
```

And your code will "work". If it is a fine design? No!

The correct thing there is to have a parent package that encompasses everything you are doing, that is above the "lib" and "utils" directories, so that both directories are viewed as subpackages.

Let's say you call it "myproject"  -
Then you have "myproject.lib" and "myproject.utils"  - and you can import either by fully specifying these names, or, doing `..lib.deep_restore` from inside the "utils" subpackage.

For that to work all you need is: add an empty `__init__.py` file to the "myproject" directory, and either work from the super-directory for that (i.e.  the directory containing the `my_project` directory), or properly install `my_project` as  an "editable package" - for that you need a [minimal "setup.py"](https://github.com/maet3608/minimal-setup-py/blob/master/setup.py) file, in that parent directory, and run `pip install -e .` .